# Access 2010 VBA on KeyPress Pause for seconds before initiating

Tags: ms-access, timer, vba, delay

I'm creating an auto-filter feature in Access 2010 Forms using VBA. 
My goal is to do the following:

- If the user presses an Enter key - do a search
- If user presses any letter character key or number key then do the following

  1. Check to make sure the length of the search string is greater than 3 characters.
  2. If the first condition is fulfilled is true then WAIT 0.5 seconds
  3. After 0.5 seconds if the length of the new search text is equal to the old then call a search *(the program will assume the user stopped typing and is waiting for a result)*

I'm thinking my problem is that I'm trying to execute all of this in the `_KeyPress` event.

```
Private Sub search_txt_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
   Dim txt As String, stxt As String
   txt = Me.search_txt.Text

   'If the enter key is pressed, then search
   If (KeyAscii = vbKeyReturn) Then
        stxt = "*" & txt & "*"
        Call Module2.searchJobs(stxt, 0)
   Else
   End If

   'If the key pressed is a letter character or number
   If (KeyAscii >= 48) Then

       'If the search value is greater than 3 characters
       If (Len(txt) > 3) Then

           'Pause for 3 seconds
           Call Pause(0.5)

           'If the string lengths are still equal to each other then search
           If (Len(txt) = Len(Me.search_txt.Text)) Then
               stxt = "*" & txt & "*"
               Call Module2.searchJobs(stxt, 0)
           Else
           End If
       Else
       End If
   Else
   End If
End Sub
```

Here's my Pause Function

```
Public Function Pause(NumberOfSeconds As Variant)
 On Error GoTo Err_Pause

 Dim PauseTime As Variant, start As Variant

    PauseTime = NumberOfSeconds
        start = Timer
    Do While Timer < start + PauseTime
        DoEvents
    Loop

Exit_Pause:
   Exit Function

Err_Pause:
   MsgBox err.Number & " - " & err.DESCRIPTION, vbCritical, "Pause()"
   Resume Exit_Pause

End Function
```

Comment: Thats kinda what I was thinking but I don't know how else to program it

Comment: What you are implementing is called "Search as you type", and it is not really necessary to re-invent it, there are many sample implementations. E.g. here: http://allenbrowne.com/appfindasutype.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA is not "multi-threading". So, when you call your `Pause()` function, it doesn't do anything and any action the user do (including key press) are void, so the approach is not correct.

Instead of using a `Pause()` function, use the `timer` of your form:

You should enable the timer instead of calling a `Pause()` function, and move your check-length logic in the timer event. When you're entering the timer event, you disable the timer.

Something like this :

```
    ' Add Load event to the form
    Private Sub Form_Load()
        Me.TimerInterval = 0 ' disable timer
    End Sub

    ' Add Ontimer event to the form
    Private Sub Form_Timer()

        Dim txt As String, stxt As String

        Me.TimerInterval = 0 ' disable timer

        txt = Me.search_txt.Text

        'If the string lengths are still equal to each other then search
        If (Len(txt) = Len(Me.search_txt.Text)) Then
            stxt = "*" & txt & "*"

            Call Module2.searchJobs(stxt, 0)
        Else
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub search_txt_KeyDown(KeyAscii As Integer, Shift As Integer)
      Dim txt As String, stxt As String
       txt = Me.search_txt.Text

       'If the enter key is pressed, then search
       If (KeyAscii = vbKeyReturn) Then
            stxt = "*" & txt & "*"
            Call Module2.searchJobs(stxt, 0)
       Else
       End If

       'If the key pressed is a letter character or number
       If (KeyAscii >= 48) Then

           'If the search value is greater than 3 characters
           If (Len(txt) > 3) Then

               ' enable timer to 0.5 second
               Form.TimerInterval = 500 'milliseconds

           Else
           End If
       Else
       End If
    End Sub
```

Additionally, take care to this:
When you enter the `KeyDown` event, your `search_txt.Text` will not contain yet the last letter pressed by the user.